# Facing an connection error with Snowflake python connector using VSCode

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000179277B0898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /session/v1/login-request?request_id=b90b3ca0-102a-4fd0-ac49-52231d445d9e&request_guid=bfc249fd-50c4-417f-b9d3-7aad681bdb96
[2021-10-28T04:35:07.797Z] HTTPSConnectionPool(host='%3cqc98024.central-us.azure%3e.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=b90b3ca0-102a-4fd0-ac49-52231d445d9e&request_guid=bfc249fd-50c4-417f-b9d3-7aad681bdb96 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000179277B05F8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mnagendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
(self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
File "C:\Users\mnagendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Users\mnagendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

### During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

What could be this issue?? I faced an OCSP error and I gave these settings in the snowflake connection string. Still it fails.

```
insecureMode=True,
ocsp_fail_open=False
```

Comment: Please provide the code where the connection is being established by removing the account details and any username information (as-in put it with dummy values) for review.

Comment: https://qiuyujx.medium.com/azure-functions-connect-to-snowflake-a-simple-test-of-the-snowflake-connector-python-133a0c90c585
Followed the same process and getting above error in
http://localhost:7071/api/<test_functioname>?schema=TPCH_SF1&table=NATION

Comment: @SrinathMenon Do you have any inputs?

Comment: I am waiting to get details of the test done for your specific use case than having a general read of the link. It is necessary to know what is being done specifically to understand and provide any inputs.

Comment: We are trying to connect with snowflake using python connector with Azure functions in  Azure Data factory.

Comment: Does the Snowflake account name have hyphen in it? As in is it something like "abc-def"? If yes, can you change hyphen to underscore and test, for eg: use "abc_def".

Comment: @SrinathMenon Thanks for your input. I tried the same, still getting the same error.

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000197102936D8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /session/authenticator-request?request_guid=04b07737-a9f8-4360-aa3f-fa15a1ed7f20

Comment: http://localhost:7071/api/<func_name>?schema=TPCH_SF1&table=NATION is not responding to my function call

Comment: Also, I am trying everything in the snowflake, Azure trial account. Is that an issue?

Comment: No, this is not an issue. Can you share the code sample screenshots for further review?

Comment: srinath. Fixed this issue by correcting my HTTP request statement.The schema and  table name has to be provided by default in my HTTP request. I tried with the parameters and it worked. Thank you so much for your response.